# Including git code in the rmarkdown documents while using bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Is there any way possible to include code for different languages in `Rmarkdown` documents while authoring books using `bookdown` package? I have looked at the `knitr` option like [`engine`](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) with possible values like `python`, `awk`/`gawk` and the executable path can be set using `engine.path`.

````
```{r, engine='python'}
print "Will this code chunk be hidden?"
```
````

However, I would like to just insert code (eg: `git`) in the Rmarkdown document without executing it.

For example, like including in the markdown documents

````
```git
git init
```
````

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want the code to be executed, you can embed it like:

````
```
code not executed
```
````

You can also have code highlighting in specific languages:

````
```css
my_css{}

```
````

For your git command, this is execution from terminal, so you can highlight it with:

````
```sh
git init
```
````

Comment: Thanks for pointing the answer which is present in my question itself.

Comment: Well, at the end, I was not sure what you were really looking for because you edited your question while I was answering it. But I guess this is the answer...